# Organizing an EF4 data layer?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity Framework 4, and I am wondering, what's the best way to organize my data layer--the code that accesses EF4?

At this point, my data layer is set up like this:

- **DataStore class:** Holds a reference to the EF4 ObjectContext, and contains methods to open, close, and persist the ObjectContext to storage.
- **Repository classes:** One class for each entity, with methods to create, fetch, and delete entity objects.

Is there a better way to organize this functionality for EF4? I've looked for articles/blogs on the subject, but I'm not finding much. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a [generic repository](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx) for Entity Framework that makes access very easy.  No need to write a separate repository for each entity, just:

```
MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext();
Repository<MyEntity, MyDataContext > myEntityRep = new Repository<MyEntity, MyDataContext>(ctx);
myEntityRep.Add(new MyEntity() {//property settings});
```

This repository totally abstracts the Entity model, allowing for creating, modifying, and deleting entities.

Comment: That's a good point. I do use a generic Repository class as a base class for my Repositories. It eliminates most of the plumbing code needed for Repository classes. The only code I need is for queries that are unique to a particular entity.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like I am using a reasonable approach. Selected this answer because of the code included. Any other suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the repository classes for each entity type (I know them as [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)). One class for all queries easily becomes too monolithic hard to maintain.

Comment: I think we are in agreement on that point. I use a separate Repositorey class for each 'root' entity type; i.e., the types I will execute queries on. +1 for the reference to DataMapper--thanks!